# Calling spss script from C#

Tags: c#, spss

I have an IBM SPSS script that pulls data from spss and save as a csv file.
Can i call this script directly using c#? Kindly help.

Script example

GET 
  FILE='D:\Folder\spssFile.sav'
 /KEEP 
var1
var2
var3
.
save translate out ="D:Folder\csvFile.csv" /type=csv /FIELDNAMES .
EXECUTE.

Comment: You can execute anything on the command line from within C# (or any programming language, really).  What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share what you've tried so far so that community can help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are many SPSS specific commands here and I suggest to use a SPSS library developed in .net

There are many online, you can google but maybe the following can be a nice starting point.

[SPSS.NET](https://github.com/AArnott/SPSS.NET)